# How to reset input field on Escape to previous value

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Whats the proper way to set an input field to its previous value, when escape key is pressed?

I found this directive:

```
.directive('resetWithEsc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on('keydown', function(ev) {
                if (ev.keyCode != 27) return;

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    controller.$setViewValue("");
                    controller.$render();
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

but it says `TypeError: Cannot read property '$setViewValue' of null`

I also tried to store the prev. value in $scope.temp and used directive to detect ESC press:

```
.directive('escKey', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('keyup', function (event) {
            console.log("UP");
            if(event.which === 27) { // 27 = esc key
                console.log("ESC");
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.escKey);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
})
```

then I used it like this:

```
<input data-ng-focus="temp = mymodel.value"
    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" esc-key="mymodel.value = temp" 
    type="text" data-ng-model="mymodel.value"
/>
```

It detects proper the escape key, and if I set `esc-key="mymodel.value = 'TEST'"` it also sets the input field to `'TEST'`, but with the variable it's not working.

So whats the best option to do so? I need it dynamic for use in repeat loops.

Comment: How do you define the "previous value"? You're trying too hard, I think. You don't need a complex directive for this. You just need to restore the value that's saved, which isn't difficult. The question is, where does the saved value come from?

Comment: `data-ng-click="temp = mymodel.value"` if I do `{{temp}}`in template it shows the correct value

Comment: So every time a user clicks the input? That seems fragile and unreliable. It also won't work for tabbed focus, etc.

Comment: you'r right, should be `data-ng-focus` I changed it.

Comment: Still not a good approach. A tab out and a tab in triggers an overwrite of the true previous value. Where does the initial value come from?

Answer (score 0):

removing `updateOn: 'blur'` and resetting `temp` did the trick ...

```
<input data-ng-focus="temp = mymodel.value"
    esc-key="mymodel.value = temp; temp='';" 
    type="text" data-ng-model="mymodel.value"
/>
```

Would be still happy about a cleaner solution since like to update the model actually only on blur.

Comment: Your requirement seems to be same as the first example illustrated in angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions or is it that you are not using forms?

Comment: right, but this example is static, how would it be possible to do this dynamic like in repeat loop?

Comment: You mean for inputs within ng-repeat. Something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/ShEJrA1JDtm8rqY2NwqT?p=preview If this is what you are looking for then it would be good if you can change your question

Comment: mh I wasn't aware of that a form and named input fields where necessary to do this... so you are right it would be different question. Thanks for the plnkr. really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Bharat's plunker example and tweaked it to use a directive.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('optionsExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.users = [
        {
          name: 'name1',
          data: ''
        },
        {
          name: 'name2',
          data: ''
        },
        {
          name: 'name3',
          data: ''
        },
      ];
    }])
    .directive('escape', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          element.bind('keyup', function (event) {
            if(event.which === 27) { // 27 = esc key
              ngModel.$rollbackViewValue();
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-ngModelOptions-directive-blur-production</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="optionsExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form name="userForm">
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <label>Name:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="userName{{$index}}"
                ng-model="user.name"
                escape
                ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur change'}"/>
            </label>
            <br />
            <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```